# Swift CommonCrypto Adding Error

Tags: swift, architecture, arm64, commoncrypto

module.map create files

Add the following code in the file,

```
module CommonCrypto [system] {
  header "/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
  link "CommonCrypto"
  export *
}
```

Bridging-Header file registration and

Search Paths and File Path registered in module.map

Build execution, error ...

```
ld: library not found for -lCommonCrypto for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I do not know :( Ask help Please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module CommonCrypto [system] { 
   header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h" 
   export * 
}
```

https://ungacy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IOS/Importing+CommonCrypto+in+a+Swift+framework